# Retrieve an angularjs controller defined using the module pattern

Tags: angularjs

I would like to define my controller using the module pattern like this:

```
    (function(ng, app) {

    // Controller constructor.
    function Controller($scope) {

        this.scope = $scope;
        this.scope.fmembers = [
             {
                 name: 'Member 1',
                 role: 'Head of Family',
                 age: 55
             },
             {
                 name: 'Member 2',
                 role: 'Brother of Head of Family',
                 age: 51
             }
        ];

        Controller.prototype = {

            getFMembers: function() {
                return this.scope;
            }
        };

        return( this );
    }

    // Define the Controller as the constructor function.
    app.controller('ftreeController', Controller );
})(angular, anmDesktop);
```

If I do that how can I retrieve this controller (ftreeController)  from the module? For example, I would like to use freeController in the routeprovider in app.config:

```
$routeProvider.when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', 
    controller: ftreeController'
});
```

In the routeprovider described above, I get an error (ftreeController not defined ...)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few errors in your code (like missing quotes) that I assume are copy and paste errors when making the post. Correcting those, it's just a matter of loading order.

The controller must be defined before the routes are configured and your app must be defined before both. I also put routes in a similarly-defined file to show how this could work on scale.

However, absent a loading system like AMD, I am not sure why you are choosing to define your code this way, but it **will** work.

I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lihMKE?p=preview) to demonstrate it working.

A few things to keep in mind: first, controllers in Angular are just functions. I am not sure why you created a copy of the scope and added it as a member property of the controller object nor why you declared a controller function off the prototype. Because of Angular's dependency injection, the function will have everything it needs when it runs, so we can just use a normal, plain-old javascript function. In most angular projects, controllers are just defined like this:

```
app.controller( 'myCtrl', function( $scope ) { 
    //... 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the way. I was trying to avoid exposing controllers by name (like the ones generated by angular-seed). Clearly the method controller method of app in your solution allows me to do this much better as well not define named objects. Thanks once again

Comment: @Ya.Perelman Glad I could help out. I prefer the way sprout handles modules as opposed to seed: https://github.com/thedigitalself/angular-sprout